# Can a UIPopoverController present itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

XCode 6.1.1
iOS 8.x

I inherited from a `UIPopoverController` and added a bunch of functionality.  The init method on this inherited UIPopoverController accepts a button.

The popover controller does an `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` in it's init on that button so that it can act as the handler for the pressed button that it's going to present itself on when the button is tapped.

When the button is tapped, the button handler  in my inherited UIPopoverController `-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton*)sender` catches the tap and calls
`[self presentPopoverFromRect:theButton.bounds inView:theButton ...`

In any case, after the button is pressed...
(1) The popover never displays.
(2) The exceptions breakpoint is never hit.
(3) The app crashes with a bizarre error that isn't discussed much at all on google.

> Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a
>   result variable: couldn't read its memory

Answer (score 0):

Well, something about it was a bad idea.
There was nothing in the Apple documentation about discouraging inheriting from `UIPopoverController` or requiring specific methods be implemented.

In any case, I changed my design so I don't create my own inherited popover and it's working that way.